# iMac not recognising any keyboard

Tags: keyboard, snow-leopard, imac

I have an Apple wired keyboard and a wireless Microsoft keyboard. I have been working with the Apple keyboard for a couple of months. Today I started my iMac and it didn't recognise the keyboard, I plugged the Microsoft keyboard (I worked with it for a year before I had the Apple keyboard) which works via USB (but wireless) and the iMac did not recognise it either. I tried the SMC reset, as shown [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3306626) but it didn't work.

Any idea of what's happening? I appreciate your help.

Comment: tried a different USB port?

Comment: @Tetsujin Every single one. I tried both keyboards on different computers and they work fine. I found that using a USB extension would fix the problem and it did. But it shouldn't be that way. Still doesn't work if I don't use the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Brand new iMac that refused to detect my wired keyboard.

After a lot of experimenting, I resolved the problem by removing my bluetooth keyboard from the bluetooth devices list completely and then plugging in the wired keyboard.

- Open System Preferences and select 'Bluetooth'
- A list of the devices detected (both paired and unpaired) will appear.
  Hover your mouse to the right of any connected bluetooth keyboard and press the 'x' that appears, to remove it from the list completely.
- Finally connect your wired keyboard and hopefully 'voila'. For me, everything return to normal.

Good luck, hope that helps.

Sherie

Comment: How did you get past the login screen without a keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

For any person that could have the same problem in the future: A solution seems to be plugging the keyboard on a USB extension will fix the problem.

Comment: However this should not be a desired solution.